# List manipulation: all possible sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have the following list

```
{a,{b,c},{d,f,g},e}
```

what is the fastest way to get the result lists

```
resultList={{a,b,d,e},{a,c,d,e},{a,b,f,e},{a,c,f,e},{a,b,g,e},{a,c,g,e}}
```

That is all flattened lists with all possible combinations of the elements of the inner lists ?

I do not care about the order they're obtained in, but I do not want lists like :

```
{a,a,a,a} or {a,b,b,e}
```

Note in the inner lists {b,c} and {d,f,g}, the elements (b,c,d,f,g) are actually also lists, it is not the case for the outer elements a and d.
Thank you.

Comment: `Tuples[{{a}, {b, c}, {d, f, g}, {e}}]`?

Comment: Hi, yes this almost works, I'll have to tweak it a bit, a real list example is {-3, -3, -3, -3, {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 1}, {0, 
   0}, {1, -1}, {2, -2}, {3, -3}}, {{-1, 3}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 
   0}, {3, -1}}, {{3, 3}}, {{-3, -3}}, -3, -3, -3, -3} , so the first elements are not lists, while the inner elements are lists, if all elements were lists, then it would work @MichaelE2

Comment: In addition, `Level[Transpose[{lst}],{-2}]//Tuples`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you cannot generate the list in a "uniform" way such that all elements are lists of integers (see [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249589/list-manipulation-all-possible-sublists?noredirect=1#comment625321_249589)), then this will work on lists of the form in the comment:

```
Tuples@Replace[{a, {b, c}, {d, f, g}, e}, x : Except[_List] :> {x}, 1]
```

For the list in the comment, one could also use

```
Tuples@Replace[list, x_Integer :> {x}, 1]
```

Comment: Excellent !   Thanks

Comment: (+1).  I didn't know you could link to a comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/249589/106#comment625318_249589, for example.  Very cool!

Comment: @user1066 Thanks. There's link to a comment on the time stamp (which maybe you found, though you used a shorter form).

Answer (score 9):

[`Distribute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html) with `List` as the second argument gives the desired result without additional processing of the input list:

```
Distribute[{a, {b, c}, {d, f, g}, e}, List]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, d, e}, {a, b, f, e}, {a, b, g, e}, {a, c, d, e}, 
>  {a, c, f, e}, {a, c, g, e}}
> ```